# Convert one json format to another in java

Tags: java, json

I am looking for a utility which converts one json format to another by respecting at the conversion definitions from a preferably xml file. Is there any library doing something like this in java ?

For example source json is:

```
{"name":"aa","surname":"bb","accounts":[{"accountid":10,"balance":100}]}
```

target json is :

```
{"owner":"aa-bb","accounts":[{"accountid":10,"balance":100}]}
```

sample config xml :

```
t.owner = s.name.concat("-").concat(surname)
t.accounts = t.accounts
```

Ps:Please dont post solutions for this example, it is just for giving an idea, there will be quite different scenarios in mapping.

Comment: Maybe [Jolt](http://bazaarvoice.github.io/jolt/)?

Comment: seem to be doing what i want, i will check more. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u need?

- Open input file.
- Read / parse JSON from file using a JSON library.
- Convert in-memory data structure to new structure.
- Open output file
- Unparse in-memory data structure to file using JSON library.